# How to get the specific id from foreach using codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter, bootstrap-modal

Just want to ask on how to get the ID in a specific foreach

My Controller

```
public function validate_subtopic(){

    $data = array('success' => false, 'messages' => array());
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("subtopicname", "SubTopicName", "trim|required");
    $this->form_validation->set_rules("subtopicdescription", "SubTopicDescription", "trim|required");
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class="text-danger">', '</p>');
    if($this->form_validation->run()){
        $data['success'] = true;

        $subtopic_data = array(
            'subtopicname'          => $this->input->post('subtopicname'),
            'subtopicdescript'  => $this->input->post('subtopicdescription'),
            'subjectID'         => $this->input->post('subjectID'),
            'topicID'           => $this->input->post('topicID'),
            );

        $this->addtopic_model->insert_subtopic($subtopic_data);
    }
    else{
        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
            $data['messages'][$key] = form_error($key);
        }
    }

    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

My Model

```
public function insert_subtopic($subtopic_data){
    $this->db->insert('subtopics', $subtopic_data);
}
```

My view from bootstrap modal

```
<div class="modal inmodal fade" id="addSubTopic" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"  aria-hidden="true">

    <?php 
    $att = array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'id' => "form-user_sub");
    echo form_open("topicAdd_Controller/validate_subtopic", $att);
    ?>
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
               <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                <h5 class="modal-title">Please Input SubTopic</h5>
            </div>
            <div id="the-message"></div>
            <div class="modal-body">

                <form role="form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Sub Topic Name</label>
                        <input class="form-control" name="subtopicname" id="subtopicname" type="text">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Sub Topic Description</label>
                        <textarea name="subtopicdescription" id="subtopicdescription" class="form-control">
                        </textarea>
                    </div>
                    <?php foreach($sample as $row){
                    ?>
                        <?php $index = current($sample); ?>
                        <input type="text" value="<?php echo $row['topicID']; ?> name="topicID">
                    <?php } ?>

                </form>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-white" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php form_close();?>
</div>
```

**This is the output of $sample:**
 
[image: This is the output of $sample]
The problem is I can't get the ID from the specific `foreach loop` I choose. how can I solve this?
Please help

Comment: What is the contents of `$sample`?

Comment: the content of $sample is from this controller function

Comment: public function syllabus($data){

  if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
   $getID = $this->uri->segment(3);
   $data = array();
   $query = $this->admin_model->subject_view($data);
   $query1 = $this->admin_model->topic_view($getID);
   $data['records'] = $query;
   $data['sample'] = $query1;
   $this->load->view('admin/syllabus',$data);

   //echo "$data";
  }else{
   $this->load->view('home');
  }
  
 }

Comment: Who approved the edit with code removal?

Comment: I don;t need this code. I need the exact value of `$sample`. Do you try to get id from `$sample`?

Comment: yes sir i trying to get the ID only

Comment: Do you understand that without knowing the structure of `$sample` no one can help you. Do a `print_r($sample)` and add output to your question.

Comment: sorry sir im just new at codeigniter

Comment: sir i  just newly edit and attached the output

Answer (score 0):

You can use `while(){}` method, so your script will be like this

```
$i = 0;
$res = array();
while($data = $_POST){
    $res[$i] = $data;
    $i++;
}
echo json_encode($res);
```